# How to use an asynchronous response value in an `app.get` callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to use flickrapi (https://www.npmjs.com/package/flickrapi) package. I need to authorize it:

```
Flickr.tokenOnly(flickrOptions, function(error, flickr) {
    //I need this flickr variable
});
```

and I want to use this `flickr` variable in my express code

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  //do something with flickr
});
```

How should I do it?

Comment: You can call `Flickr.tokenOnly` normally inside the `app.get` callback..just make sure to cal `res.send()` or `res.end()` to terminate the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modular approach:

Put your flickr connectivity code separate:

**flickr-public.js**

```
var Flickr = require("flickrapi"),
    flickrOptions = {
      api_key: "API key that you get from Flickr",
      secret: "API key secret that you get from Flickr"
    };

module.exports = (function(){        
    Flickr.tokenOnly(flickrOptions, function(error, flickr) {
      //handle error here
      console.log('Flickr Object Obtained');
      return flickr;
    });
})();
```

> Note: Better instantiate the flickr object in your app.js file.
>   So that the object gets created immediately when server starts. **As this flickr object is for public API only and does not need authentication again and again.**

You can instantiate the flickr object by simply requiring it in **app.js** file:

```
require('./flickr-public');
```

Now Simply access flickr object anywhere by simply requiring it.

**routes.js**

```
const flickr = require('../path-to/flickr-public');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  //use flickr object to perform actions.
});
```

**Explanation**:

From the node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching):

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to `require('foo')` will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.
>   Multiple calls to `require('foo')` may not cause the module code to be executed multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it inside your get

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Flickr.tokenOnly(flickrOptions, function(error, flickr) {
    //do something res.status(200).send('what you want here');
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use it directly inside your route callback

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  Flickr.tokenOnly(flickrOptions, function(error, flickr) {
      //call someother method to get photos etc. and finally call res.send()
      res.send(photos); // where photos is obtained from flickr or anything you can pass which should be response of you request.
  });
});
```